# debug ionic app on android device right from the start

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic 4 App, that is running without any error in the browser.
Running `ionic cordova browser --prod --release` is running fine.

But when running on the device with `ionic cordova android --device --prod --release`, I get nothing but a white screen after splashscreen. When connecting with the Chrome Dev Tools, I see that there were 8 Errors, but I cannot view them, as the Dev Tools connect after the startup of the app.

[image]

ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)          : 4.1.2 (C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework            : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.7
   @angular-devkit/core       : 0.7.5
   @angular-devkit/schematics : 0.7.5
   @angular/cli               : 6.1.5
   @ionic/ng-toolkit          : 1.0.8
   @ionic/schematics-angular  : 1.0.6

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 6.3.0, browser 5.0.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.1.4, (and 8 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v10.11.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the errors in the adb log. Try running adb logcat.

Also, you can try to place an alert as a very very first thing in your app, it will prevent further execution.